# JSF and Tomcat Possible Memory Leak

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I get this warning when ever I restart or stop Tomcat.

> SEVERE: The web application [/WebApp] created a ThreadLocal with key
>   of type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1] (value
>   [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@1fe1018d]) and a value of type
>   [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext] (value
>   [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@6d2ce054]) but failed to remove
>   it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create
>   a memory leak.

List of technology

- Primefaces 3.4.2
- JSF 2.1
- Apache Tomcat 6.0.35
- Java 1.6.0_37
- JSTL 1.1
- Netbeans 7.0.1
- MySQL

Thoughts?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be leftover libraries that are still in memory.

The main issue seems to be over time the libraries can use up all the memory and create a PermGen Error on the Tomcat server.

So the best thing to do is up the memory as much as possible and reset the webserver on occasion.

There should be a better solution but it eludes me.